# Including compiled application in build

Tags: builds, team-foundation-server

I currently maintain the build process of a suite of applications through TFS.  Our nightly build, in addition to compiling the code checked in that day, uses InstallAware to produce an installer for the application suite.  In addition to all of the items that have been compiled, there are three applications that have already been compiled and must be included in the installer.  What is the best way to get these applications to the folder where InstallAware expects to pick them up so they are properly included in the installer?

Comment: Are these applications actual dependencies of the compiled applications?

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: No.  One is used to check that certain prerequisites exist on the machine where the applications are being installed.  Another is used to clean up some information upon uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed your additional applications are not part of the nightly build: add the application binaries to the repository. See them as "artifacts", since they have to be created by a manual build step outside of your regular build.

A more sophisticated option might be to utilize NuGet for this, but that would mean to setup your own NuGet server, which is probably oversized for your needs.

Comment: I actually have my own nuget server set up, but since the additional apps aren't dependencies of any of the other projects, I couldn't think of a way to include them through this.

Comment: @DrewBurchett: I do not have any experience with nightly builds on TFS, but can't you just add some kind of "Installer" project to have a fixture for the dependencies?